# Get years from date column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

I have a column HireDate, a date column, and I would like to have a Seniority column number of years depending of Today's Date - Hire Date.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try the below and let me know

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(HireDate)),INT(DATEDIF(HireDate,TODAY(),"d")/365),"")
```

You would like to keep the decimal places, use ROUND() function:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(HireDate)),ROUND(DATEDIF(HireDate,TODAY(),"d")/365,1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. One last thing if you don't mind? I have another column for today's date, I did that calculated column yesterday using the following formula: =TEXT(TODAY(),"MM/dd"), and I am checking now and the value in the column still pointing yesterday's date 12/15, Any idea how to make this volatile? I need this column to be updated daily. Thanks in advance

Comment: Calculated column values are not automatically get updated. When an item is created or updated then only values of the calculated column get updated. If you update any other column value of this item item, you will see the values will be  recalculated and updated. What is your business requirements for this?

Comment: Hi thanks again for your help. I am trying to do a birthday reminder using flow, and I need a column to get updated daily. I am using this formula =TEXT(NOW(),"MM/dd") and also this =TEXT(today(),"MM/dd"), but still not wotking

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on your requirements. 1) How does your flow get triggered? 2) What data does the flow use to send the reminder? If you can explain it little better it would helpful

Comment: Hello, sorry for the messy explanation, let me recap this. In my SPL "employees" I have a column Birthday and I have a another column birthdayMonthDay, I am extracting the month and the day only for that column. then I have another column today's date and I am also extracting month and day from today. now I can easy compare both dates i.e 12/18 vs 12/18 so at this point I know that the person birthday is today. Now I have another column and If statement, if the person is active and today's birhtday is "yes" send the email reminder, in flow I am using recurrence to check this condition daily.

Comment: I don't think you need a separate column based on today's date in your SPL to accomplish this. Since you have already a column to hold birth date' MM/DD (12/18), you can extract MM/DD from today's date **utcNow()** in your flow, and using substring(), you can extract MM/DD. And then get the items from your list by using Query filter - BirthMinthDay -eq 'MM/DD' value in flow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer: if you want to round the numeric value down toward zero, use **[FLOOR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/floor-function-5168a039-9501-4e02-ac52-83914290ac55)** function instead.

For example, **5.27** will be calculated as **5.2** instead of 5.3; **1.7** will be calculated as **1** instead of 2.

For integer:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([HireDate])),FLOOR((TODAY()-[HireDate])/365,1),"")
```

For decimal:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([HireDate])),FLOOR((TODAY()-[HireDate])/365,0.1),"")
```